# Code for matching multiple criteria cannot handle mismatch/interruption

Tags: vba, excel

The action can be broke down as following:

1. In sheet `src2` I select the criteria using  checkbox (multiple selection possible
2. According to selected criteria, the code goes to sheet `src` and looks for the match
3. Matching items are exported to another `Dst`

Code works fine except for the situation with following selection of criteria in sheet `src2`:

```
 - Criteria 1 - selected
 - Criteria 2 - not selected
 - Criteria 3 - selected
```

That means the code cannot work with a gap between selections. It gives no error. Just nothing is exported.

```
Dim rngSelectionTable As Range
Dim tempfolderpath As String
Dim Crit As String                                                          

Set rngSelectionTable = src2.Range("options_selectiontable")                

For temprow = 1 To rngSelectionTable.Rows.Count                             
    tempselected = rngSelectionTable(temprow, 2).Value   ' Checkbox value column
    Crit = rngSelectionTable(temprow, 5).Value           ' Criteria value column
    If tempselected = True Then                          ' If checkbox selected, then ...

            For Each r In src.Range("P4:P" & LastRow)    ' Analysis range in Sheet src
                If r <> 0 Then strValue = r              ' If cell in src is Non-Empty
                If strValue = Crit Then              ' If cell in Modules_List = Criteria
                    If CopyRange Is Nothing Then       ' If nothing copied before, then
                            Set CopyRange = r.EntireRow       ' Copy entire row
                    Else
                            Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, r.EntireRow) ' Else - add this row to previously copies
                    End If
                End If
            Next r
        End If
    Next temprow

    If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then

    CopyRange.Copy
    Dst.Range("A324").Insert xlShiftDown     ' Starting cell for INSERTing the range
    End If
```

Comment: what is your intent with: `If tempselected = True Then`? Are the values  in column `2` of your Excel Table Logical expressions?

Comment: @EEM yes, column 1 is checkbox, and column 2 is connected with  it logical expression. Column 5 is criteria

Comment: Could you please post a meaningful sample of your table, that will help to reproduce the behavior...

Comment: @EEM [here](http://www.filedropper.com/multiplecriteriaexport)

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you have to change  `For Each r In src.Range("P4:P" & LastRow)` the `P4` to `P1` in the file. Then it will completely replicate my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last operation to get the unioned range to the destination worksheet is failing. Whenever that range is comprised of discontiguous rows, you cannot use it in an Insert Copied Cells operation. Try it manually on the worksheet and you will see that the option is not available.

You can loop through the unioned range's [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx) and Copy, Insert Copied Cells for each contiguous range (aka Area).

```
Dim a As Range
If Not copyRange Is Nothing Then
    For Each a In copyRange.Areas
        'Debug.Print a.Address(0, 0)
        a.Copy
        dst.Range("A324").Insert xlShiftDown     ' Starting cell for INSERTing the range
    Next a
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a very elegant solution